# Hide m3u8 file with php or html

Tags: php, html, video-streaming, m3u8

I have a .m3u8 file from an external server.

Example: (https://rt-usa.secure.footprint.net/1105.m3u8?streamType=live) The free-to-air tv signal from RT.

Is it possible to "hide" the m3u8 route using a domain?

Example: [www.mysite.com/stream/rt.php](http://www.mysite.com/stream/rt.php)

And that when it is played in VLC or a similar one, it reproduces the content by reading the source url directly.

Comment: Did you try a redirect?
Put this code on rt.php
<?php
header('Location: https://rt-usa.secure.footprint.net/1105.m3u8?streamType=live');
?>

Comment: Yes, i had tried it before and it didn't work, but thanks

Comment: I tried it with your code and it worked. Before I had tried:
`<script>if(window==window.top){window.location.replace("https://rt-usa.secure.footprint.net/1105.m3u8?streamType=live");}var url = new URL(window.location.href);var refDom =  url.hostname;</script>`

Comment: What you're trying to do is a make a proxy server.  Yes, this is possible.

Comment: @slowdmelendez360 With javascript is not possible, VLC media doesnt support javascript execution, so you're not redirected.

Comment: Note: VLC and other some player can show the original source ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible ways to to this:

1. Insert a redirect header using php file

`<?php header('Location: rt-usa.secure.footprint.net/1105.m3u8?streamType=live');`

2. In .htaccess (Apache) or NGinx.

Comment: Do you have an example for number 2?